# Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have the appropriate libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I installed Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 because the 2017 version has issues. When I start a new blank app, it only loads in with

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
```

My issue is that the program compiles and links properly to the Android emulator and some functionality exists, but when I try to use any call to 
(Resource.Id) the Id call is non existent my Resource class contains no definition for Id but this is widely used through out all demos and tutorials.
Similarly I cannot use Android:crs="" as crs is also not defined.

I suspect it's the references to libraries that are the issue but I can't find which is the problem.

I'm also concerned that my `Mono.Android` library is version 0.0.0.0

Any advice would be wonderful

Comment: Uninstall completely Xamarin and reinstall it. Also ensure you have installed the correct Android SDK.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 and I had no issues for develop in Xamarin. Which issues did yours have?

Comment: solved, im not specifically sure when it got fixed but i opened a different project type and the libraries were there so i copied the references and using statements and i was good to go.